# AJAX POST REQUEST throws MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i dont know what im doing wrong please help!

i have this in my view

```
<div class="search">
    {{Form::open(array('url'=>'','method' => 'post'))}}
        {{Form::text('keyword',null,array(
            'class' => 'form-control input-lg',
            'placeholder' => 'Enter keyword...(e.g. post title)'
        ))}}<bR>
        <div class="submit1">
        {{Form::submit('Search',array(
            'class' => 'btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block',
        ))}}
        </div>
    {{Form::close()}}
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="searchs">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </thead>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

            $('form').submit(function(e){

                e.prevenDefault();

                var formData = new FormData();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'admin/search',
                    method:'post',
                    processData:false,
                    contentType:false,
                    cache:false,
                    dataType: ,
                    sucess:function(data){},
                    error:function(){}
                });
    });
</script>
```

and my routes

```
Route::get('/admin', array(
            'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
            'as' => 'index'
            ));
        Route::post('/admin/search', array(
            'uses' => 'AdminController@search',
            'as' => 'search'
            ));
```

i just want to know what im doing wrong, or if im missing something i really want to learn ajax but im stuck with this one.. i hope someone can help with this

Comment: My guess is that your form is actually submitting on click - not via the ajax request (event bubbling) and is therefore posting to your route '/admin' which is a does not allow post requests.

Comment: interesting but what do you suggest? what should i do?

Comment: Just spotted this:  e.prevenDefault(); should be  e.preventDefault();

Comment: still the same.. and youre correct i return to this route Request URL:http://localhost:8000/

Comment: ok try adding e.stopPropagation(); before your ajax call basically you want it in a state where the button click doesnt reload the page

Comment: still the same, im guessing that my problem is in my routes or in my form url ??? what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72475/discussion-between-nan-and-sean-arce).